# Linux/Ubuntu Shell Script SLURM command

Tags: shell, slurm

is it possible to execute the SLURM Commands such as srun or sacct inside a bash shell file( e.g. file.sh).

file.sh

#!/bin/bash

sacct --user
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5m0Rw.png)

I am getting an error such that :

Slurm - sacct: error: slurm_persist_conn_open_without_init: failed to open persistent connection to host:localhost:6819: Connection refused

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You should have the same error when running the same command in the interactive bash command shell, it is equivalent.

Comment: dear @Poshi , the problem is when I type the code which is : sacct --user userName --format=JobID,State in the Terminal it works, but when I take the same code command to the  filename.sh and execute it with the sbatch jobName.jobscript, it exactly give me the the error which is : [slurm-users] Slurm - sacct: error: slurm_persist_conn_open_without_init: failed to open persistent connection to host:localhost:6819: Connection refused

Comment: That's a different issue.

The issue is not by being executed in a `bash` script, but being executed in a different machine. Take a look at the error message: it complains about `localhost:6819` not being available. Are you sure you are running the appropriate SLURM daemons in that machine?

Comment: This means that I should understand that the issue is not about that the Slurm command that I mentioned before "sacct" can be executed on the filename.sh bash shell script file BUT this is another error that I got from the HPC Clusters which contain 20 nodes for parallel executions, what do you mean that am I sure that running the appropriate SLURM daemons in the machine? and do you know, why it could be that it complains localhost:6819 ? @Poshi

Comment: I imagine that it complains about localhost:6819 because it must be the default location of the location set up in the configuration. What I mean when I ask if your SLURM daemons are up and running is just that: the daemon that should handle your query should be running. Otherwise, the client will always complain that it can't reach the server.

Comment: ?? Which eval command? Better start a new question with all the relevant data, a minimal reproducible example and no images, as usual.

Comment: @Poshi you are right I will delete my last comment for this post, I posted with a new title